Issue with Navigation Bar after Cloning and Moving Files in React(Next) Project
I cloned the repository and moved the files with the following commands:
1. clone https://github.com/adrianhajdin/portfolio.git 

2. cd portfolio 

3. mv * ..

After running npm run dev, everything looks good, but when I click on the About button or similar buttons in the navigation bar, there is an issue.
Problem Description
When I click on the About button in the navigation bar, the page does not update correctly, and it seems like nothing happens, although the URL changes. Here are the before and after screenshots:

before:

enter image description here

after:

enter image description here
Note that the scrollbar does not move!
Attempted Solutions
I tried fixing it by running the following commands:

npm audit fix --force
npm install --legacy-peer-deps

Code
Here is the code for the Home page and the Navbar component:
Home.tsx:
const Home = () => {
  return (
    <main className="relative bg-black-100 flex justify-center items-center flex-col overflow-hidden mx-auto sm:px-10 px-5">
      <div className="max-w-7xl w-full">
        <FloatingNav navItems={navItems} />
        <Hero />
        <Grid />
        <RecentProjects />
        <Clients />
        <Experience />
        <Approach />
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </main>
  );
};

FloatingNavbar.tsx:
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  motion,
  AnimatePresence,
  useScroll,
  useMotionValueEvent,
} from "framer-motion";
import Link from "next/link";
import { cn } from "@/lib/utils";

export const FloatingNav = ({
  navItems,
  className,
}: {
  navItems: {
    name: string;
    link: string;
    icon?: JSX.Element;
  }[];
  className?: string;
}) => {
  const { scrollYProgress } = useScroll();

  // set true for the initial state so that nav bar is visible in the hero section
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true);

  useMotionValueEvent(scrollYProgress, "change", (current) => {
    // Check if current is not undefined and is a number
    if (typeof current === "number") {
      let direction = current! - scrollYProgress.getPrevious()!;

      if (scrollYProgress.get() < 0.05) {
        // also set true for the initial state
        setVisible(true);
      } else {
        if (direction < 0) {
          setVisible(true);
        } else {
          setVisible(false);
        }
      }
    }
  });

  return (
    <AnimatePresence mode="wait">
      <motion.div
        initial={{
          opacity: 1,
          y: -100,
        }}
        animate={{
          y: visible ? 0 : -100,
          opacity: visible ? 1 : 0,
        }}
        transition={{
          duration: 0.2,
        }}
        className={cn(
          // change rounded-full to rounded-lg
          // remove dark:border-white/[0.2] dark:bg-black bg-white border-transparent
          // change  pr-2 pl-8 py-2 to px-10 py-5
          "flex max-w-fit md:min-w-[70vw] lg:min-w-fit fixed z-[5000] top-10 inset-x-0 mx-auto px-10 py-5 rounded-lg border border-black/.1 shadow-[0px_2px_3px_-1px_rgba(0,0,0,0.1),0px_1px_0px_0px_rgba(25,28,33,0.02),0px_0px_0px_1px_rgba(25,28,33,0.08)] items-center justify-center space-x-4",
          className
        )}
        style={{
          backdropFilter: "blur(16px) saturate(180%)",
          backgroundColor: "rgba(17, 25, 40, 0.75)",
          borderRadius: "12px",
          border: "1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.125)",
        }}
      >
        {navItems.map((navItem: any, idx: number) => (
          <Link
            key={`link=${idx}`}
            href={navItem.link}
            className={cn(
              "relative dark:text-neutral-50 items-center  flex space-x-1 text-neutral-600 dark:hover:text-neutral-300 hover:text-neutral-500"
            )}
          >
            <span className="block sm:hidden">{navItem.icon}</span>
            {/* add !cursor-pointer */}
            {/* remove hidden sm:block for the mobile responsive */}
            <span className=" text-sm !cursor-pointer">{navItem.name}</span>
          </Link>
        ))}
        {/* remove this login btn */}
        {/* <button className="border text-sm font-medium relative border-neutral-200 dark:border-white/[0.2] text-black dark:text-white px-4 py-2 rounded-full">
          <span>Login</span>
          <span className="absolute inset-x-0 w-1/2 mx-auto -bottom-px bg-gradient-to-r from-transparent via-blue-500 to-transparent  h-px" />
        </button> */}
      </motion.div>
    </AnimatePresence>
  );
};


Question:
How can I fix the navigation issue so that the page updates correctly when clicking the navigation buttons?


The issue has nothing to do with installing dependencies. You'd clonned the project installed dependencies and run locally and it works.
The issue here is that the author of the project uses anchor scrolling for navigating.
Try not to remove margin/padding of the main text block (transforming concepts...) adter clicking on an url in the navbar.

What I should do?
